# Why doesn't view show full screen with Launch Image in iPhone6 in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I use Launch Screen (launchscreen.storyboard) and checked "Use Auto Layout"in ViewControllers and launchscreen.storyboard.

But when I set Launch Screen File in General -> App Icons and Launch Images, views (UIView subclass) in ViewController doesn't show full screen in except iPhoneSE and 6. (Background image in ViewController shows full screen.)

Delete "Launch Screen File" in App Icons and Launch Image, views show full screen.
(I tried to use xib file for launchImage, but it was same.)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally happens when your launch image is not correct. iOS determines the screen size on the basis of the size of the launch image. I faced the similar issue for iPhone 6, I fixed that issue by adding launch image as png in the application (not in images.Assets) and adding the UILaunchImages dictionary in info.plist.
    But here too for iPhone 6 use landscape image. here is the source code of info.plist. But we sure that all the launch images are of correct size.

```
<array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>A
            <string>Default-320x480</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeLeft</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-320x480</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeRight</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 480}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-Landscape-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeLeft</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>7.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-568h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{320, 568}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-375x667</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeLeft</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-375x667</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeRight</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 667}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-2208x1242</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeLeft</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-2208x1242</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeRight</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{414, 736}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-2048x1536</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeLeft</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.1</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-2048x1536</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>LandscapeRight</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{768, 1024}</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```